# knockout.js not mapping observable array from json

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Can't map json to observable array. I use code from tutorial (http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

```
function Movie(data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.description = ko.observable(data.description);
    this.duration = ko.observable(data.duration);
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.imdb_id = ko.observable(data.imdb_id);
    this.original_name = ko.observable(data.original_name);
    this.poster = ko.observable(data.poster);
    this.type = ko.observable(data.type);
    this.year = ko.observable(data.year);
}

function MovieListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.moviesArray = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.searchQuery = ko.observable();

    self.searchMovies = function () {
        $.getJSON("/api/v1/movies/search/", {"query": self.searchQuery }, function(allData) {
            var mappedMovies = $.map(allData.movies, function(item) { return new Movie(item) });
            console.log(mappedMovies); // in this line output: [Movie, Movie, Movie, Movie, Movie, Movie]

            self.moviesArray(mappedMovies);
            console.log(self.moviesArray); // in this line output: []
        });    
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new MovieListViewModel());
```

I do not understand what is wrong.

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: Have you tried: `console.log(self.moviesArray());`?

Comment: It's a really strange thing but `console.log(anyObservableArray)` shows `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
{"query": self.searchQuery }
```

Should be

```
{"query": self.searchQuery() }
```

---

This

```
console.log(self.moviesArray)
```

Should be

```
console.log(self.moviesArray())
```

Comment: Thanks, i am new in javascript :)

Comment: Knockout is strange in this way.  You don't need to do this for non-observable values.